# Centos 8 PATH cleared

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Im having trouble on a CentOS 8 VM. for some reason whenever we reboot the VM it gives us the

```
bash: sed: command not found
```

for most basic commands such as `ls` for example. We figured out that the `PATH` environment variable was not being written for some reason and had to manually add it with

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

but whenver we restart the VM the same issue occurs again.

Im not really experienced with the linux os; so if someone could just guide me on how to debug this issue?

I tried stoping the cronjobs that might be clearing the environment (even tho none were doing so). Also we tried the

```
source /etc/profile.d/profile
```

but that didn't seem to do work ...

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The **PATH** environment variable is defined in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` as following:

```
# Set up a default search path.
PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
export PATH
```

It can be appended by more directories using the `/root/.bash_profile`, assuming you're using **bash** as default shell, like this example:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/mybin

export PATH
```

Have you tried this method ?